# Getting text or json from server with native javascript can't work correctly

Tags: javascript, web

I need to get regions and cities from batuta.medunes.net. Program work correctly for regions but for cities can't work correctly even though I use same function and response from server is same like in first case with regions.

Here is code with functions that I use on *onchange* event at *select* tag in html:

```js
var regions;
var get="";
function addRegion() {
    var e = document.getElementById("countries");
    console.log(e.selectedIndex);
    console.log(countries[e.selectedIndex].alpha2Code);
    var url="http://battuta.medunes.net/api/region/"+countries[e.selectedIndex].alpha2Code+"/all/?key=4b64da74d07ae8718ec91742d9a73b0a&callback=cb"
    get="reg"
    JsonpHttpRequest(url, "cb")
}

function addCity() {
    var countr = document.getElementById("countries");
    var regs = document.getElementById("regions");
    var regStr=regions[regs.selectedIndex].region;
    regStr = regStr.replace(/\s/g, '%20');
    console.log(regStr);
    var url="http://battuta.medunes.net/api/city/"+countries[countr.selectedIndex].alpha2Code+"/search/?region="+regStr+"&key=4b64da74d07ae8718ec91742d9a73b0a"
    console.log(url);
    get="city";
    JsonpHttpRequest(url, "cb");
}

function JsonpHttpRequest(url, callback) {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = url;
    document.body.appendChild(e);
    window[callback] = (data) => {
        if(get=="reg"){
            regions=data;
            console.log(data); 
            select = document.getElementById('regions');
            removeOptions(select);
            for (var i = 0; i<Object.keys(data).length; i++){
                var opt = document.createElement('option');
                console.log(data[i].region);
                opt.innerHTML = data[i].region;
                select.appendChild(opt);
            }
        }
        else{
            console.log(data); 
            select = document.getElementById('cities');
            removeOptions(select);
            for (var i = 0; i<Object.keys(data).length; i++){
                var opt = document.createElement('option');
                console.log(data[i].city);
                opt.innerHTML = data[i].city;
                select.appendChild(opt);
            }
        }
    }
}

function removeOptions(selectElement) {
       var i, L = selectElement.options.length - 1;
       for(i = L; i >= 0; i--) {
          selectElement.remove(i);
       }
    }
```

I used console.log() and when I change region problem is stoping execution function *JsonpHttpRequest(url, callback)* at line before *...window[callback] = (data) => {...*
so I can't manipulate with response from server.
Here is Console from browser:

[image]

Comment: I would recommend generating new JSONP callback function names for each request

Comment: Sorry but I'm beginner with JS and what you exactly mean when u say "generating new JSONP callback function names for each request"?

Comment: All your callback functions are named `cb`. I would generate new ones for each request. This is what jQuery does for their JSONP requests

Comment: Same thing is happened... :(